# How to call on next page through readmore link

Tags: php, html, find

I'm using this script in php. I have successfully added the readmore option but i want any user that clicks on this link will then open up a new page with the full article and with gallery pictures. But i want it to open into the same window.

```
echo "<div id=message>";
$text = $row["message"]; 
<?php echo substr($text,0,500);?>
<a href="#"?id=<?php echo $row['id']?> title="Full Story Of <?php echo $row['title']?>">Read More &raquo;</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

please try the following:

```
echo "<div id=message>";
$text = $row["message"]; 
<?php echo substr($text,0,500);?>
<a href="readmorepage.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']?>" title="Full Story Of <?php echo $row['title']?>" target="_self">Read More &raquo;</a>
```

although _self is default value of the same so you need not write it.

Comment: @user2210257: you can create as many links as you want. you would just need to manage the links href accordingly. please let me know if there is any problem.